# Git push/clone not working using HTTPS without any sort of firewall/proxy only in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, heroku, github

Git push when using HTTP gives this

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/something.git/': 
       Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Network is unreachable
```

While git clone gives this

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/something.git/': 
       Failed to connect to github.com port 80: Network is unreachable
```

The same works on Windows using HTTP on same machine and on Ubuntu using SSH.

I tried looking at git config files but couldn't achieve anything.

I can access it via browser and HTTP remote for Heroku doesn't work too.

I tried purging and installing again but it made no difference.

ping github.com works; if that makes a difference

This is a personal computer at home directly connected to router and I have not enabled any firewall consciously.

Comment: Does the repo exist?

Comment: Check this: `ssh -T git@github.com` is it working?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Yes I have tried with various popular/big public/private repos on GitHub and Heroku

Comment: @codeWizard Yes. That works and so does Git with SSH. It is not working with HTTPS.